# Function got an unexpected keyword argument - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate MFCC of an audio signal using python_speech_features module by James Lyons [(Github page)](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features). I modified it a bit so I can switch between using Mel Scale and Bark Scale, like this:

```
def mfcc(signal, samplerate=16000, winlen=0.025, winstep=0.01, numcep=13,
         nfilt=26, nfft=512, lowfreq=0, highfreq=None, preemph=0.97, 
         ceplifter=22, appendEnergy=True, mel=True,
         winfunc=lambda x:numpy.ones((x,))):

    if mel:
        feat, energy = fbank(signal, samplerate, winlen, winstep, nfilt,
            nfft, lowfreq, highfreq, preemph, winfunc, mel=True)
    else:
        feat, energy = fbank(signal, samplerate, winlen, winstep, nfilt,
            nfft, lowfreq, highfreq, preemph, winfunc, mel=False)
    feat = numpy.log(feat)
    feat = dct(feat, type=2, axis=1, norm='ortho')[:,:numcep]
    feat = lifter(feat,ceplifter)
    if appendEnergy:
        # replace first cepstral coefficient with log of frame energy 
        feat[:,0] = numpy.log(energy) 
    return feat
```

When `mel=True`, it will calculate using Mel Scale equation and when `mel=False` it will calculate using Bark Scale equation. But, when I try to use this function in another program, I got this error:

```
 TypeError: mfcc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mel'
```

Anyone can help me fix this problem?

Comment: yes, i copy the files from the original one into different folder and edit it there.

Comment: I think you somewhere import this function.
Try to copy the files `base.py` and `sigproc.py` into completely different folder and modify it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
The given code is for the function only; there's no call and no context to support a repair we might provide.

Comment: You omitted the trackback that would show which function call resulted in the exception.  Report does not match behavior.  When I call `mfcc(1, True)`, I get `NameError` for `fbank`.  So passing `mel` to `mfcc` is fine.  PS: If code were correct, you would just need one call to fbank with `bool(mel)`.  But that is probably not right either.

Comment: how did you solve it?